# How to make ball bounce off wall with PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, python-3.8

Before you criticize me for not Googling or doing research before asking, I **did** research beforehand but to no avail.

I am trying to create the Atari Breakout game. I am currently stuck with making the ball bounce off walls. I did research on this and I found a lot of blogs and YouTube videos (and also Stack Overflow questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256104/how-to-make-ball-bounce-off-triangle-in-pygame) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368857/how-to-make-ball-bounce-off-paddle)) talking about PyGame's vector2 class. I also read the PyGame documentation on vector2 but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I am currently writing a script to make the ball bounce off walls. In the beginning, the player is requested to press the spacebar and the ball will automatically move towards the north-east direction. It should bounce off the top wall when it hits it, but instead, it went inside. This is my approach:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screenWidth = 1200
screenHeight = 700

window = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Atari Breakout')

class Circle():

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel_x = 1
        self.vel_y = 1


def check_hit():
    global hit
    if (((screenWidth-box.x)<=box.radius) or ((box.x)<=box.radius) or ((box.y)<=box.radius) or ((screenHeight-box.y)<=box.radius)):
        # meaning  hit either four walls
        if (((screenWidth-box.x)<=box.radius) or ((box.x)<=box.radius)):
            # hit right, left
            print('hit right, left')
            hit = True
        elif (((box.y)<=box.radius) or ((screenHeight-box.y)<=box.radius)):
            # hit top, bottom
            print('hit top, bottom')
            hit = True
            

# main loop
run = True
box = Circle(600,300,10)
hit = False
                                                  # (screenWidth-box.x)<=box.radius     hit right wall
while run:                                        # (box.x)<=box.radius                 hit left wall
                                                  # (box.y)<=box.radius                 hit top wall                        
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)                  # (screenHeight-box.y)<=box.radius    hit bottom wall

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and (box.y)>box.radius:
        while True:
            box.y -= box.vel_y        
            box.x += box.vel_x

            window.fill((0,0,0))
            pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (box.x, box.y), box.radius)
            pygame.display.update()

            check_hit()
            if hit == False:
                continue
            elif hit == True:
                break

        if (box.y)<=box.radius or (screenHeight-box.y)<=box.radius:
            # hit top, bottom
            box.vel_x *= 1
            box.vel_y *= -1
            print('changed')

            if (box.y)<=box.radius:
                # hit top
                print('hi')
                while True:
                    box.x += box.vel_x               # <-- myguess is this is the problem
                    box.y += box.vel_y


                    window.fill((0,0,0))
                    pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (box.x, box.y), box.radius)
                    pygame.display.update()
                



        elif (screenWidth-box.x)<=box.radius or (box.x)<=box.radius:
            # hit right, left
            box.vel_x *= -1
            box.vel_y *= 1






    window.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (box.x, box.y), box.radius)
    pygame.display.update()


    print('Where are you going')

pygame.quit()
```

I guess the problem is where I marked.  Which is here:

```
        if (box.y)<=box.radius or (screenHeight-box.y)<=box.radius:
            # hit top, bottom
            box.vel_x *= 1
            box.vel_y *= -1
            print('changed')

            if (box.y)<=box.radius:
                # hit top
                print('hi')
                while True:
                    box.x += box.vel_x               # <-- myguess is this is the problem
                    box.y += box.vel_y


                    window.fill((0,0,0))
                    pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (box.x, box.y), box.radius)
                    pygame.display.update()
```

but I don't know why. My theory is: the ball travels upwards, it hit the top wall, `check_hit()` kicks in and make `hit` = True, then the `vel_x` and `vel_y` is changed accordingly (if hit top wall, `vel_x` should remain the same while `vel_y` should be multiplied by -1). Then it will move down, hence "bounce" off the top wall.

**Note:** for now I only have the top wall working. The other three will be done when I can figure out how to bounce off the top wall first.

Can you help me see what's the problem? And if this kind of operation requires the use of the vector2 class, can you explain it to me or give me a place to learn it?

Comment: Why are there so many parentheses in your if statements?

Comment: I thought it would look nicer lol. Turn out to be as messy

Comment: Also, `if ... == True:` --> `if ... :`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue are the multiple nested loops. You have an application loop, so use it.
Continuously move the ball in the loop:

```py
box.y -= box.vel_y        
box.x += box.vel_x
```

Define a rectangular region for the ball by a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

```py
bounds = window.get_rect() # full screen
```

or

```py
bounds = pygame.Rect(450, 200, 300, 200)  # rectangular region
```

Change the direction of movement when the ball hits the bounds:

```py
if box.x - box.radius < bounds.left or box.x + box.radius > bounds.right:
    box.vel_x *= -1 
if box.y - box.radius < bounds.top or box.y + box.radius > bounds.bottom:
    box.vel_y *= -1
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
box = Circle(600,300,10)

run = True
start = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while run:                     
    clock.tick(120)  

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        start = True

    bounds = pygame.Rect(450, 200, 300, 200)
    if start:
        box.y -= box.vel_y        
        box.x += box.vel_x

        if box.x - box.radius < bounds.left or box.x + box.radius > bounds.right:
            box.vel_x *= -1 
        if box.y - box.radius < bounds.top or box.y + box.radius > bounds.bottom:
            box.vel_y *= -1 

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), bounds, 1)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (box.x, box.y), box.radius)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: when can i use the ```.top``` ```.bottom``` etc. method?

Comment: `.top` `.bottom` are virtual attributes. See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). You can use them on any instance of `pygame.Rect`, every time.