# the car moves and changes direction when it hits the window edge

Tags: python, pygame, rotation, collision-detection, pygame-surface

The car is moving straight. When it hits the window edge it moves backwards then
changes direction at an angle of 45 degrees clockwise and keeps moving straight.
if it hit the edge of the window again, it would do the same

I've made the code below. I was only able to stop and reverse the car
when it hits the edge of the window. How to change the direction
of the car, make it go straight, and keep the program running
and it will only stop if we close the window?

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def base(cX,cY):
    screen.fill(whitdull)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,whitdull,[0,0,1050,600],4)
    
    screen.blit(text1,[150,230])
    
    # Copy image to screen:
    screen.blit(player_image, [cX,cY])
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(ct)


def carMovement(b0XX,b0YY,bDirection):
    sX = 5      # 5 pixel/clock  Direction right-left
    sY = 5      # 5 pixel/clock  Direction upward-downward
    
    while True:
        
        # Direction to the right
        pX = sX
        pY = 0
        
        b0XX = b0XX + pX
        b0YY = b0YY + pY
        if b0XX == 970:
            b0XX = 970 - sX
            backward(b0XX,b0YY,Direction)
            
        # Copy image to screen:
        base(b0XX,b0YY)

    return b0XX,b0YY

def backward(b0XX,b0YY,bDirection):
    sX = 5      # 5 pixel/clock  Direction right-left
    sY = 5      # 5 pixel/clock  Direction upward-downward
    
    while b0XX >= 900:
        
        # Direction to the right
        pX = sX
        pY = 0
        
        b0XX = b0XX - pX
        b0YY = b0YY - pY
        if b0XX == 900:
            b0XX = 900 + sX
            
            
        base(b0XX,b0YY)
    return b0XX, b0YY

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Define some colors
white=(250,250,250);   whitdull=(247,247,247)
black=(70,70,70)   ;   blue =(45,127,184) 
gold  =(248,179,35);   green=(0,176,80)
yellow=(254,240,11);   gray=(208,206,206)

#Setting font-size
font1 = pygame.font.Font(None,150)

text1 = font1.render("Bom-bom  Car",True,white)


# preparing  the  screen
width = 1050 ; height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
pygame.display.set_caption('Bom-bom Car')
screen.fill(whitdull) 


player_image = pygame.image.load("Car-2.jpeg").convert()
#rotasi = pygame.transform.rotate(player_image, -45)


#initial condition
b0X = 0; b0Y = 250; Direction = 2      # initial car position, Direction 2 = to the right

ct = 20
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# program utama Pygame
while True:
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            b0X,b0Y = carMovement(b0X,b0Y,Direction)
            
    base(b0X,b0Y)
    
    # Get the current mouse position (x,y)
    player_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    xm=player_position[0]
    ym=player_position[1]
       
#end program
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRdYh.png)
[image]

[image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBXN7.jpg)
[image]

Comment: how to get the car backwards when it hits the window edge then moves forward

Answer (score 0):

Never implement additional loops to control the game. You have the application loop. Use it!

Use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) objects to define the position and movement of the player. The initial movement is (0, 0). Additionally define a speed for the player:

```py
player_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(player_image.get_width() // 2, screen.get_height() // 2)
player_move = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
speed = 10
```

As soon as the mouse is pressed, define the direction of movement and scale the length of the movement vector by the `speed` with [`scale_to_length()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length):

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    dx = event.pos[0] - player_pos.x
    dy = event.pos[1] - player_pos.y
    if dx != 0 or dY != 0:
        player_move = pygame.math.Vector2(dx, dy)
        player_move.scale_to_length(speed)
```

Add up the motion vector (`player_move`) to the position of the player ( `player_pos`) in the application loop:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    player_pos += player_move
```

Get the bounding rectangle of the player. I recommend to read [Why is my collision test always returning 'true' and why is the position of the rectangle of the image always wrong (0, 0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730329/pygame-collide-rect-function-always-returning-true/57730378#57730378):

```py
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = (round(player_pos.x), round(player_pos.y)))
```

Once the player reaches the edges of the window, *reflect* the player on the edges like a pool ball. See also [How to make ball bounce off wall with Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802794/how-to-make-ball-bounce-off-wall-with-pygame/59803018#59803018):

```py
if player_rect.left < 0:
    player_rect.left = 0 
    player_pos.x = player_rect.centerx
    player_move.x = abs(player_move.x)
if player_rect.right > screen.get_width():
    player_rect.right = screen.get_width()
    player_pos.x = player_rect.centerx
    player_move.x = -abs(player_move.x)
if player_rect.top < 0:
    player_rect.top = 0 
    player_pos.y = player_rect.centery
    player_move.y = abs(player_move.y)
if player_rect.bottom > screen.get_height():
    player_rect.bottom = screen.get_height()
    player_pos.y = player_rect.centery
    player_move.y = -abs(player_move.y)
```

Compute the angle of the movement vector and rotate the player around its center. See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144) and [How to rotate an image(player) to the mouse direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603835/how-to-rotate-an-imageplayer-to-the-mouse-direction/58604116#58604116):

```py
angle = player_move.angle_to((1, 0))
rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(player_image, angle)
rotated_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center = player_rect.center)
```

Finally redraw the scene:

```py
screen.fill(whitdull)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, whitdull,[0,0,1050,600],4)
screen.blit(text1,[150,230])
screen.blit(rotated_player, rotated_rect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Complete example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CarMovement](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CarMovementReflect#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Define some colors
white=(250,250,250);   whitdull=(247,247,247)
black=(70,70,70)   ;   blue =(45,127,184) 
gold  =(248,179,35);   green=(0,176,80)
yellow=(254,240,11);   gray=(208,206,206)

#Setting font-size
font1 = pygame.font.Font(None,150)
text1 = font1.render("Bom-bom  Car",True,white)

# preparing  the  screen
width, height = 1050, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
pygame.display.set_caption('Bom-bom Car')

player_image = pygame.image.load("Car-2.jpeg").convert()

#initial condition
ct = 20
player_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(player_image.get_width() // 2, screen.get_height() // 2)
player_move = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
speed = 10

# program utama Pygame
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dx = event.pos[0] - player_pos.x
            dy = event.pos[1] - player_pos.y
            if dx != 0 or dY != 0:
                player_move = pygame.math.Vector2(dx, dy)
                player_move.scale_to_length(speed)

    player_pos += player_move
    player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = (round(player_pos.x), round(player_pos.y)))
    if player_rect.left < 0:
       player_rect.left = 0 
       player_pos.x = player_rect.centerx
       player_move.x = abs(player_move.x)
    if player_rect.right > screen.get_width():
       player_rect.right = screen.get_width()
       player_pos.x = player_rect.centerx
       player_move.x = -abs(player_move.x)
    if player_rect.top < 0:
       player_rect.top = 0 
       player_pos.y = player_rect.centery
       player_move.y = abs(player_move.y)
    if player_rect.bottom > screen.get_height():
       player_rect.bottom = screen.get_height()
       player_pos.y = player_rect.centery
       player_move.y = -abs(player_move.y)

    angle = player_move.angle_to((1, 0))
    rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(player_image, angle)
    rotated_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center = player_rect.center)
    
    screen.fill(whitdull)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, whitdull,[0,0,1050,600],4)
    screen.blit(text1,[150,230])
    screen.blit(rotated_player, rotated_rect)    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(ct)
```